# Python X and (Y or Z) and or operators ignoring my int() casting

Tags: python

all, I'm doing some beginner python exercises and I'm having trouble with checking integers from list to be both positive and whole numbers.

```
arr=[]
print("Enter numbers, terminate with space: ")
while True:
    x=(input())
    if x==' ':
        break
    arr.append(int(x))
    if x>0 and (x%2==0 or (x+1)%2==0):
        print("Numbers are both positive and whole.")
```

this code comes back with an error that says

```
if x>0 and (x%2==0 or (x+1)%2==0):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`
```

even though I casted `x` as `int` with `arr.append(int(x))`
any help is appreciated!

Comment: sorry for messy code, how should i go about editing it to make it easier on the eyes?

Comment: The answers support markdown so adding "```" before and after code blocks will work

Comment: `(x%2==0 or (x+1)%2==0)` will always be true. What's the point of that check?

Comment: This is the code that worked for me:  ```arr=[]
print("Enter numbers, terminate with space: ")
while True:
    x=(input())
    if x==' ':
        break
    x=float(x)
    arr.append(x)
for x in arr:
    if x>0 and (x%2==0 or (x+1)%2==0):
        print("The number ", x, "is both positive and whole")
    elif x>0 and x%2!=0 and (x+1)%2!=0:
        print("The number ", x, "is positive but not whole")
    else:
        print("The number", x, "is negative")```             again sorry for messy code... I'm just no good at editing

Comment: If you cast `x=int(x)`, then `x` will always be true for `(x%2==0 or (x+1)%2==0)`

Comment: @ErezZinger Put your code in an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Your code will never print `positive but not whole`. `int()` always returns integers, they never have a fraction. Use `float()` if you want to include the fraction.

Answer (score 2):

`arr.append(int(x))` doesn't change the value of `x`. It puts an `int` into the list, but `x` still contains a string.

If you want to change `x`, you need to reassign the variable:

```
x = int(x)
arr.append(x)
```

Comment: hello, thanks for quick answer! seems it fixed the initial error but after terminating the loop to check all the numbers it gives out the same error once more

Comment: That must be a different problem.

Comment: Hello, I managed to fix the problem, if anyone is reading this and is interested what did the trick I will post it. Thanks for everyone trying to help!

Comment: If you have a different answer than the ones that were posted, you should post it.

Comment: If input is negative or decimal, `x=int(x)` will throw an error, thus not able to reach the check for `(x%2==0 or (x+1)%2==0)`

Comment: @BlackRaven There shouldn't be an error if it's negative.

Comment: yes, i mean example `-1.2`, `-0.5` (sorry so still a float)

Comment: Those aren't integers.

Comment: Yes `-1` or `2` would work, but `1.5` or `-0.1` will fail

Comment: @BlackRaven Of course, because those are not integers. You said "negative **or** decimal", you meant to say just "decimal".

Comment: Agree. this is what I meant. If input is decimal, `x=int(x)` will throw an error, thus not able to reach the check for `(x%2==0 or (x+1)%2==0)`

Answer (score 0):

You added integer to the list, but didn't change type of X. so this would be a better approach to your problem:

```
x=int(x)
arr.append(x)
if x>0 and (x%2==0 or (x+1)%2==0):
```